# How I can simplify query for getting nested JSON in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have 3 entities in db. Boards, Lists and Cards. They have one to many relationship. Boards contain Lists, Lists contain Cards.

**Boards:**

```
CREATE TABLE boards(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    title text NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE boards_lists(
    board_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES boards ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    list_id integer PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES lists ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

**Lists:**

```
CREATE TABLE lists(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    title text NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE lists_cards(
    list_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES lists ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    card_id integer PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES cards ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

**Cards:**

```
CREATE TABLE cards(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    text text NOT NULL
);
```

For example, I have 2 routes:
1. **GET /boards** - must return deep nested JSON with boards, lists and cards

```
[
 {
   id: 1,
   title: 'board 1',
   lists: [
     {
       id: 1,
       title: 'list 1',
       cards: [
         {
           id: 1,
           text: 'card 1'
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

2. **GET /lists** - must return the same JSON as I described above, without boards, just lists with cards.

So, I need get boards with all lists and cards inside from db. I use this query:

```
WITH full_lists AS (
    SELECT l.*,
        COALESCE (json_agg(c) FILTER (WHERE c.id IS NOT NULL), '[]') AS cards
    FROM lists AS l
    LEFT JOIN lists_cards ON (l.id = list_id)
    LEFT JOIN cards AS c ON (c.id = card_id)
    GROUP BY l.id
)
SELECT b.*,
    COALESCE (json_agg(l) FILTER (WHERE l.id IS NOT NULL), '[]') AS lists
FROM boards AS b
LEFT JOIN boards_lists ON (b.id = board_id)
LEFT JOIN full_lists as l ON (l.id = list_id)
GROUP BY b.id
```

It works fine, but I think that it's very cumbersome, in addition I have two similar SELECT queries for getting boards and lists. How I can simplify it?

Comment: Why do you need to perform that logic on DB's side? You don't do any filtering. Can't you load all the data into app and process it there? It will be easier to code/maintain and more efficient because you won't send JSON (which is generally heavier than raw data).

Comment: I thought that this action must be done on DB side. You mean that would be more simplier to make 3 queries (for each entity) and merge data in app?

Comment: First of all: you are not forced to do anything. :) But yes, this approach will definitely be simplier, easier to extend and maintain. It also might be more efficient but this you would have to benchmark. It's just a suggestion. Working with sql is almost always harder then on app's side and IMHO should be avoided unless performance demands it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm newbie in db, and it seemed to me that many queries will be processed slower than one big :)

Comment: That's not true generally. And sometimes one big query can kill your db (e.g. because of lock exhaustion). Also the difference between 1 query and 1000 queries might be huge but difference between 1 and 3 probably won't even be noticable.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use row_to_json to optimize this:
https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql